# Null Column despite using Coalesce

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT 
    i.item, 
    COALESCE(COUNT(r.item_id), 0) AS TotalRating, 
    SUM(r.rating) as RatingSum,  
    re.tR as TotalReview,
    AVG(r.rating) AS AverageRating
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN ratings AS r
    ON (r.item_id = i.item_id)
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT item_id,COALESCE(COUNT(item_id),0) AS tR
    FROM reviews
    WHERE item_id = '{$itemId}') AS re
ON re.item_id = i.item_id  
WHERE i.item_id = '{$itemId}';
```

I keep getting this error:

```
#1048 - Column 'item_id' cannot be null
```

That line pertains to the sub-query from table `reviews`.  I am using `Coalesce`; why does it still say its null?

Comment: Maybe it's referring to the *other* `item_id`

Comment: `COALESCE(COUNT(item_id),0)` makes no sense to me since `COUNT()` never returns `NULL`

Comment: Can you create sqlfiddle with sample data and post desired output for your query?

Comment: Is there a null value in the item_id field in your database somewhere?

Comment: @peterm  The query works perfect except when there are no matching `item_id`'s to count from table `review`

Comment: @rncrtr  I don't believe so. the `item_id` count is null if there are no matching id's.  That's the null that I get.  Query works fine when there s a match.

Comment: try doing a count(*) instead of count(item_id) just to see if that is an issue?

Comment: @rncrtr  I get the same error, does that mean its the other item_id at fault?

Comment: It seems like that could be the case. Also, what is this {$itemId} you're passing in? Could that ever be null under any circumstance? It almost sounds like it is trying to use a null to perform the where clause. The error may seem to apply to the coalesce line, but I doubt that is true.

Comment: @rncrtr  itemId can never be null.  I am basically counting  reviews and ratings from users.  If an item has no reviews it basically kills the whole query.  If it does, both counts are accurate.

Comment: @ExplosionPills  You are correct now that I test.  Any way to test around this?

Comment: I think this error message is only supposed to appear in an INSERT, if you try to store NULL in a non-NULL field. Is this SELECT being used as part of an INSERT?

Comment: @KickingLettuce I suppose you could use `COALESCE(item_id, '')`  Maybe that will work

Comment: You don't need `COALESCE` in the subquery. If there are no rows matching `${item_id}`, the query returns no rows.

Comment: @Barmar the sub query works great on its own. You are correct.  If I test for null on item_id and set it as zero, then it says re.item_id doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe my logic is flawed, can someone show me a better query to achieve same results perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT i.item,
       r.totalRating, COALESCE(r.ratingSum, 0), COALESCE(r.averageRating, 0),
       re.totalReview
FROM items i
JOIN (select COUNT(*) totalRating, SUM(rating) ratingSum, AVG(rating) averageRating
      FROM ratings
      WHERE item_id = '${item_id}') r
ON (1 = 1)
JOIN (select COUNT(*) totalReview
      FROM reviews
      WHERE item_id = '${item_id}') re
ON (1 = 1)
WHERE item_id = '${item_id}'
```